how to permanently stop vmmem from running
I have a pc running 1 gb of vmmem process for ram and unable to find a reason why. It will not allow me to end task it says access denied and I tried some of the sources I found in other but none of the solutions do anything I tried
wsl --shutdown it does nothing (how am I supposed to run it I used it in command prompt, but it just shows me options.


Is this a business-owned computer or a personal device? Are you running WSL? Do you have any other sort of virtualization you are aware of running on the computer? What options does the command show you?

its a business pc.  No WSL should not be running and no vmware are running or even installed which is why i dont understand why its using that resource

You should be talking with your business' dedicated IT staff then. They may have products installed on your computer for business' purposes. Because they own and control your computer, we really cannot help you here.

do you have docker or any containerization software?

@music2myear i am on IT staff. This is for a user.  I had 2 sys admins and another IT support user try to assist as well we finally found a solution.

and your solution was...?
